# Migrating from VBA Excel 2003

Tags: migration, ms-office, excel-2003

I have a series of big excel files that work like a program, but I hate beeing tied up (stuck in VBA for excel 2003), so...

Whats the best way to implement a gui over a excel vba program (office 2003)? (are there any tools for that... I want to move away from the office suite, but still have it in the background)

Or what's the easiest alternative for migrating this code to a more open language.
Any ideias?

Comment: Well I started the project a few years ago and now I'm stuck on office 2003 on all PCs at work.... even the new ones.
I wanted to use if possible open source. But what I must do is move away from office and make it into a "real aplication"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [VSTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/dd253198.aspx)?

Comment: 1+ Really interresting. Looks like tonight I'll do doing some reading :)

Answer (score 0):

[Resolver One](http://www.resolversystems.com/products/resolver-one/ms-excel.php) is a Python spreadsheet system with strong support for importing from MS Excel.  It's often used for the situation you describe.